# Django - how to set language manually?

Tags: django, django-views

I set the language in my Django app during login with:

```
user_language = user.profile.language
translation.activate(user_language)
request.session['django_language'] = user_language
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
```

What happens is that app doesnt load language as I would like to. 
If I use in my template `{% get_current_language %}` I see in my template 'en' or 'pl'. I press 'refresh page' and language changes. It's also strange that if I change a language for one user, it also affects every user.

My question is how do I set the language manually, so it stays constant, and for only specific user. I would like to set the language just after the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is built-in Django middleware that let's users control their own language settings.**

From the [Django docs (read this link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

> If you want to let each individual user specify which language they prefer, then you also need to use the LocaleMiddleware. LocaleMiddleware enables language selection based on data from the request. It customizes content for each user.

You can use [`get_current_language()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) once you're sure you've fully implemented everything you need from the [Translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/).

Comment: thanks for you directing me to this site. just needed to add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to MIDDLEWARE setting.